# Calculating the orbits of binary stars around their barycentre

Tags: science-based, orbital-mechanics, stars, solar-system

I've been building a world, partly for test reasons (making sure my spreadsheet works, and so i know what i need to add to it) and partly for fun, but for calender reasons i need to know the orbital period of my binary star system.

More specifically, as i am putting this in a spreadsheet, *i need the calculations to figure out the orbital period* - preferably dumbed down a little as, when searching myself, i couldn't make heads or tails of it.

**Star 1:**

Mass: 1.07 Solar Masses

Distance from Barycentre:   0.0709724389 AU

**Star 2**

Mass: 0.853 Solar Masses

Distance from Barycentre:   0.0890275611 AU

**Orbital Eccentricity:** 0.41

Comment: You need the masses of both bodies and the distance between their centers to calculate the orbital period (you can express the mass in terms of solar masses if it's more convenient).

Comment: I've added those to the question.

Comment: Your distances from the barycenter of the system only apply if the orbits are circular, otherwise you'll have to qualify them. I assume these are the maximum distances from each other?

Comment: No.  Their absolute max separation is 0.4512... i'm getting the sinking feeling that i've been worldbuilding wrong

Comment: [Barycenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter), from ancient Greek _barys_ (heavy); from the same Greek word we have _barometer_ (measures the _weight_ of the atmosphere) and _baritone_ (_deep_ voice).

Comment: Hannah, you should review the basic terminology involved here. Consider asking on Astronomy !

Comment: There is a similar Question on astronomy - https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-can-i-calculate-the-orbital-periods-in-a-binary-star-system, but i didn't understand it at all (Hence asking for a dumbed-down version) Please state what you are referring to about how i've worded the question and i'll try to correct/improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have it pretty figured out already. You just need to apply Kepler's Third Law. For two bodies orbiting a barycenter, the square of the orbital period is proportional to the cube of their mean distance and inversely proportional to the sum of their masses.

For these things I always use WolframAlpha to avoid doing calculations by hand. For your parameters (with a semimajor axis of 0.08 AU, which is the average distance from each star to the barycenter) the result is [143 hours](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=kepler%27s%20third%20law,%201.07%20solar%20masses,%200.853%20solar%20masses,%200.08%20au).

Comment: Ok, when finding the mean of my two distances, i come out with either 0.08 (with (Distance1+Distance2)/2 )  or 0.12 with (Distance1+Distance2/2). Also, What do you mean by inversly proportional?

Comment: @Hannah I've just corrected the calculation (it should be 0.08 AU as you said, I think). The "inversely proportional" bit refers to Kepler's Third Law. The more massive the objects, the shorter their orbital period.

Comment: Ok. ta. I'm still a little confused over the exact equations (that i'll need to put into the spreadsheet) but you've been very helpful

Comment: ... I think i've found the equation i'm looking for - as it seems to have given the most accurate result (According to Wolfram Alpha) of all the ones i've tried, which is P = SQRT(A^3/(M1+M2)... where P is the orbital period and A is the Max separation... a second opinion would be helpful though, as my result is 1dp off.

Comment: What you found is what I found, which is basically a form of Kepler's 3rd, but I'm still doubtful what A means in this case (since Kepler's laws are usually explained with reference to very different masses).

Comment: A is measured in AU... i think (and i've put it as the max separation, which is how i've gotten the figure to 0.000 accuracy, but the figure after that is wrong by 1. either way for the case i'm using it for it seems like an acceptable margin of error so i'll stick with it for now